# What would be the prototype of printf?

Tags: c

look at these calls closely:

```
printf("hello, world\n");
printf("%d", 2);
printf("%d%g\n", 2, 2.3);
```

we see that printf can accept any type and any number of args.
however we know that functions in c only take fixed length args and should have a compatible prototype to match the arg.
what would be the prototype of printf ?

Comment: if you don't know variadic functions, this question cannot be answered !

Comment: and if you already know variadic functions, why on earth did you post this question? :-/

Answer (score 9):

> we know that functions in c only take fixed length args

So you know it incorrectly. `printf` (and several other standard library functions) use a language feature called [*variable argument list*](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%20variable%20arguments).

Btw its <strike>signature</strike> declaration looks more or less like this (may be different on your platform):

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

Comment: whether you write the "format" or not doesn't matter in function declaration

Comment: @AbhinavPandey, at least if readability (by humans) doesn't matter, that is :-)

Comment: "function signature" really is a C++ term associated with overloading; C doesn't do overloading so it only has a function declaration.

Comment: Wouldn't ommiting format in the declaration make it possible to call `printf(1);` without even a compiler warning?

Answer (score 3):

```
extern int printf (__const char *__restrict __format, ...);
```

The ellipsis indicate that this function uses a [variable argument list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C).

Comment: Why the leading underscores for `const` and `restrict`?  Those are perfectly good keywords in C99, and the right ones for the function declaration.  (`__format` is a reserved identifier, but may be correct for a particular implementation.)

Comment: Because the declaration is copied-and-pasted from the GNU C Library version of `stdio.h`.

Comment: Dan04: exactly. Lazy me ;-)

Comment: @dan04: Using `__const` and `__restrict` makes it possible to use the same header file in both C89 and C99 modes.  A proper C89 compiler must work with correctly on a program that starts with `#define restrict 12345` before its `#include <stdio.h>` but would not be required to work correctly if the program started with `#define __restrict 12345`.